# Magento 2 bin folder missing can't run any cli commands

Tags: magento2, cli, bin-magento

I am working on a client's shop, and the bin folder is missing, how can that be possible? Can I recreate it with the files inside? 
Its a noob question but I never faced this issue...

```
-rw-r--r--  1     88 Sep 29  2015 .anonymizer.cfg
-rw-rw-r--  1    3201 Mar 23 08:06 api.php
drwx--x--x  6    4096 Mar 23 08:06 app
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Aug 21  2015 cgi-bin
-rw-r--r--  1     636 Sep 13  2015 config.rb
-rw-r--r--  1      14 Sep 13  2015 contributors.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1    2928 Mar 23 08:06 cron.php
-rw-rw-r--  1    1621 Mar 23 08:06 cron.sh
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Dec 21  2015 data
-rw-rw-r--  1       3 Mar 23 08:06 deleteme.txt
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Sep  8  2015 deploy
drwxrwxr-x  3    4096 Mar 23 08:06 dev
drwx--x--x  3    4096 Oct 22  2015 dev.bak
drwx--x--x  5    4096 Aug 19  2016 downloader.bak
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Sep 13  2015 .ebextensions
drwx--x--x  3    4096 Mar 23 08:06 errors
-rw-rw-r--  1    1150 Jan 10  2017 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r--  1    5952 Mar 23 08:06 get.php
drwx--x--x  7    4096 Apr 27 10:51 .git
-rwxrwxr-x  1     830 Feb 26  2018 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1      53 Aug 15  2017 google162ffb936c709b25.html
-rw-rw-rw-  1  670813 Sep 19 23:05 GoogleShopping_full.xml
-rw-rw-rw-  1   90829 Sep 20 00:00 GoogleShopping_inventory.xml
-rw-------  1      31 Sep 13  2015 heartbeat.php
-rw-rw-r--  1    6986 Mar 23 08:06 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--  1    5886 Jan 10  2017 .htaccess.sample
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Mar 23 08:06 includes
-rw-rw-r--  1    2596 Mar 23 08:06 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1    2305 Mar 23 08:06 index.php.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1    6442 Mar 23 08:06 install.php
drwx--x--x 22    4096 Mar 23 08:06 js
drwx--x--x 28    4096 Dec  1  2017 lib
-rw-rw-r--  1   10421 Jan 10  2017 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1   10679 Jan 10  2017 LICENSE.html
-rw-rw-r--  1   10410 Jan 10  2017 LICENSE.txt
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Sep 13  2015 log
-rw-rw-r--  1    2222 Mar 23 08:06 mage
-rwxrwxr-x  1    4970 Mar 23  2017 magebirdpopup.php
drws--s--x 20    4096 Mar 21  2018 media
-rw-r--r--  1   1438 Aug 29  2015 php_errorlog
-rw-rw-r--  1     886 Jan 10  2017 php.ini.sample
drwx--x--x  4    4096 Oct 29  2015 pkginfo
-rwxrwxr-x  1    363 Dec  1  2017 po_compressor.xml
-rwxrwxr-x  1   1300 Dec  1  2017 po_core_new_question_to_support.html
-rwxrwxr-x  1    2889 Dec  1  2017 Potato_Compressor.csv
-rwxrwxr-x  1    2215 Dec  1  2017 Potato_Core.csv
-rwxrwxr-x  1    1501 Dec  1  2017 Potato_ImageOptimization.csv
-rw-rw-r--  1  599428 Mar 23 08:06 RELEASE_NOTES.txt
drwx------  3    4096 Sep 30  2015 scripts
-rw-r--r--  1     228 Sep 13  2015 .scss-lint.yml
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Mar 23 08:06 shell
-rw-rw-rw-  1   30988 Sep 19 23:05 sitemap.xml
drwx--x--x  5    4096 Oct 29  2015 skin
drwx--x--x  2    4096 Sep 21  2015 stage
drwsrwsrwx 13    4096 Aug  9  2017 var
drwxr-xr-x  3       4096 Aug 16  2017 .well-known
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like a Magento 1

are you sure it's Magento 2 and you in the right folder?

you can use something like: [MagentoVersion.com](http://MagentoVersion.com) to check your website version

for Magento 1 you can use [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) for cli

Comment: it says Magento ver. 2.2.5 in the dashboard

Comment: you sure this is the folder and you on the right server? magento 2 have no mage, skin, media, shell, js folders! these all are M1 only.
you should expect folders like pub, setup, update and bin for sure!
check the app/etc if you found `local.xml` it's 100% M1 then you can check the db in there, and find what site this is.

Comment: Ok, there is app/etc/local.xml and not theres is no env.php like magento2...
But I am confused now, can magento 2 frontend dashboard run on Magento 1 frame?

Comment: I checked mage.php and it says its 1.9.3.8 version which means its not magento 2, and Im very confused how magento 1x runs magento 2 front end...

Comment: for sure it's impossible, as I told before you're not on the website/server! 1. you can do a simple test add any file like `test.txt` on the root then try to open it `example.com/test.txt` it shouldn't open. 2.check with the client and confirm the data.
3. you can check the db config in the `local.xml` open the db find the table `core_config_data` and find the value of `web/unsecure/base_url` it should tell you what the url for this Magento 1 website

Comment: Yeah all toegether, client gave m ewron gaccount, where older version was stored before the update, I though Im going nuts, but now managed to get correct account where I can see magento 2 structure. Thanks for your help!